# Workaround for Select AS WHERE

Tags: sql, t-sql

Is there any way in TSQL to use variable/Alias in `WHERE` clause?

```
Select First_Name as FN from PERSON
Where FN like 'D%'
```

The reason I ask is what if I have nested selects.  Do I have to put the entire nested select statement again in my Where clause to filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many similar questions point out, the answer is "no". The solution is typically a CTE or subquery. This "limitation" is a property of the SQL language, not of a particular database.

SQL Server does have a third method (which is why I am answering). This is more appropriate for a complex expression. Your example isn't a great example, but you can use `outer apply`:

```
select p2.fn
from person p outer apply
     (select p.First_Name as FN) p2
where p2.fn like 'D%'
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am converting Oracle to TSQL and I see where they are using it like:  ...from (select blah from Master) "Age"...and then later using Where "Age" < 25...  was hoping TSQL could do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you put the "nested select" (THis is referred to as a *subquery*) in the From Clause:

```
select FN 
from (select First_Name as FN 
      from PERSON) z
```